# Sublimetext 3 Vintage - Insert multiple lines with Open command

Tags: vim, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

With open command you can insert a new line above or below the current line.
Is there a way to insert multiple lines?

I've tried `2o 3O 2\o 2\o` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why the question is tagged `vim`? In Vim `3o<esc>` works perfectly.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Vintage mode in Sublime text is an emulation of vim.